# Compare .csv files with BASH while merging one column

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am having issue with matching the files together, $GROUP_MEMBERS_FILE hold the info about the members of a group in csv format:

```
group,mail
eg.
GROUP1,test1@group.com
GROUP2,test2@group.com
```

The second file $GROUP_CHANGES_FILE holds the info about the adding to group membership, in .csv format:

```
date,group,mail
eg.
2021-04-01T14:25:37+00:00,GROUP2,test2@group.com
2020-02-01T12:23:47+00:00,GROUP1,test1@group.com
2020-02-01T13:23:47+00:00,GROUP1,test3@group.com
2021-02-01T12:23:47+00:00,GROUP3,test4@group.com
```

And I am trying to accomplish to filter that matches of $GROUP_MEMBERS_FILE to $GROUP_CHANGES_FILE, although with parsing also the date column to $FILTERING_FILE. The furthest I got, is finding the match, however I am not able to parse the date value to $FILTERING_FILE, to have the same format as this result example:

```
date,group,mail
eg.
2021-04-01T14:25:37+00:00,GROUP2,test2@group.com
2020-02-01T12:23:47+00:00,GROUP1,test1@group.com
```

The code which is not able to give me the date merged, however is matching the files(all files are not sorted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","};FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' $GROUP_MEMBERS_FILE $GROUP_CHANGES_FILE > $FILTERING_FILE
```

Does someone has an idea how to do it the easiest way ? Thanks, Appreciate that!

Comment: [edit] your question to contain concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: I didn't vote to close this question btw - can't imagine why that happened to you straight out the gate without giving you a chance to fix it!

Comment: @EdMorton, ...eh, the potential for folks to fix things is why close votes can be retracted, or reversed with reopen votes. Wasn't my close vote either, but I absolutely _would_ have cast one if I'd seen the question in its earlier state (and I'd be happily retracting it now).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 3 close votes closes the question instantly, then when you vote to re-open it after the OP fixes it almost no-one is looking at it any more as it's closed and so it can take days, if ever, to get enough reopen votes to actually get it reopened. So, unlike down votes, close votes should be used sparingly. It'd be great if, after a question is closed, one of the people who voted to close it could retract that vote or vote to reopen it and it'd instantly get reopened but unfortunately it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't really understand the explanation in your question, sorry, but this seems to be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]; next} ($2,$3) in a' members changes
2021-04-01T14:25:37+00:00,GROUP2,test2@group.com
2020-02-01T12:23:47+00:00,GROUP1,test1@group.com
```

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton, I am sorry, it does not work.. although I will try to explain one more time: In a $Changes file, I need to find the entry of $Members, matching group and mail (one mail can have multiple groups- Active Directory output), and this needs to be printed out to as: date, group, email  ( the awk I provided has the functionality I need- matching, but missing the "date" column, which needs to be attached from the $Changes file